# How to know customer new payment date is arrived in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to make a monthly subscription-based app where a customer can buy a property on a monthly basis payment. The customer will continue to pay a certain amount for the property each month until the value of the property is paid.

Everything is working fine. However, now I want to know how can I check which customers' new payment dates have arrived. How do I filter out customers who haven't made an arrived payment yet?

models.py

```
class Property(models.Model):
    """Property Model"""

    area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0,)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    """Customer Model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prop_select = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    remaning_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        property_price = self.prop_select.price
        payment_done_by_customer = Payment.objects.filter(customer=self).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or Decimal('0')
        # Remaining Amount of each customer
        self.remaning_amount = property_price - payment_done_by_customer
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_pending_customer(self):
        last_payment = Payment.objects.filter(customer=self, created_at__lte=datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=60)).order_by('-pk')[:1]
        for i in last_payment:
            present = i
            if present:
                self.pending_customer = False
                self.save()
        return print('Present: ' + str(present))

class Payment(models.Model):
    """Payment Model"""

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='payment')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
```

Comment: Filter based on `Payment.datetime`?

Comment: would you like to explain it something more about  for customers new payment date is arrived or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view to verify subscription status, call it everytime users sign into the app to verify whether their subscription is still valid or not, you can do this by checking against the current date

```
from datetime import datetime

def verify_subscription_status(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=pk)
    payment_details = Payment.objects.get(customer=customer)
    expiry = payment_details.date_time
    end_date = datetime.strptime(expiry, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    is_valid = not (datetime.now() > end_date)
    return JsonResponse({ 'status': is_valid })
```